# Webclient C# on Google Forms returns (405) Method Not Allowed from the server

Tags: c#, webdriver, google-forms, http-status-code-405

See the title for details. I'm using notepad and compiling this through a batch file connected to the batch file on Windows, though I seriously doubt that's the issue here. I am not using any external libraries, nor do I wish to.

```
using(WebClient X = new  WebClient()){
    try{

        System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection collection = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
        collection.Add("entry.1928682659",label);
        collection.Add("entry.1413176565",data);
        collection.Add("submit","Submit");
        X.UploadValues(new Uri("https://docs.google.com/forms/example"),"POST",collection);
        Console.WriteLine("Sending over "+data); // Not the actual link.
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Console.WriteLine("Didn't send "+data);
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    Console.WriteLine(file, new System.IO.FileInfo(file).Length);
}
```

This is only part of my code, but label and data represent strings I want to upload (the latter is a UTF-8 string converted from a binary data array, if that makes any difference).

Anyway, as the code would suggest, it tells me whether it believes it was successful in sending. It never is. It prints the error, "System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed."

Comment: Evidently "POST" is not allowed for the endpoint you're accessing. Have you verified that you're using the correct method?

Comment: How do I tell what the correct method is? I imagine it's in the HTML code of the webpage?

Comment: If it's not an actual public-facing Google API that you're using (and you're trying to automate form filling), then I recommend using a proxy tool like Fiddler to inspect the request the browser makes vs the request your code makes.

Comment: I'll try that, thanks for the suggestion. I changed the method to "GET", and I got a new error-- "System.Net.ProtocolViolationException: Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type", which, from a bit of research, evidently means that Get isn't the right request either.